# Component's prop doesn't update in React Native with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I need some help with my app and Redux! (Currently, i hate it aha)

So, i have a notification page component which fetch some datas and i need to put the data length into my redux store to put badge on my icon in my tabbar!

My Main Reducer :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import NotificationReducer from "./NotificationReducer";

export default function getRootReducer(navReducer) {
    return combineReducers({
        nav: navReducer,
        notificationReducer: NotificationReducer
    });
}
```

My Notification reducer

```
const initialState = {
    NotificationCount: 0
};

export default function notifications(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_COUNT' :
            console.log('REDUCER NOTIFICATION SET_COUNT',state)
            return {
                ...state,
                NotificationCount: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

My Action :

```
export function setNotificationCount(count) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
          console.log('Action - setNotificationCount: '+count)
          dispatch( {
            type: 'SET_COUNT',
            payload: count,
          });
    };
};
```

My Component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, SectionList, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Notification } from '@Components';
import { ORANGE } from '@Theme/colors';
import { NotificationService } from '@Services';
import Style from './style';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as Actions from '@Redux/Actions';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height

export class NotificationsClass extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            NotificationCount: undefined
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        this.updateNotifications();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log('receive new props',nextProps);
    }

    async updateNotifications() {
        this.props.setNotificationCount(10); <---
        let data = await NotificationService.get();
        if (data && data.data.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ dataSource: data });
            console.log(this.props) <-- NotificationCount is undefined
        }
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.dataSource.length > 0) {
            return (
                <SectionList
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled
                    refreshing
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.notificationId}
                    style={Style.container}
                    sections={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderRow(item)}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => this.renderSection(section)}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return this.renderEmpty();
        }
    }

    renderRow(data) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} key={data.notificationId}>
                <Notification data={data} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }


}


const Notifications = connect(
    state => ({
        NotificationCount: state.NotificationCount
    }),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
)(NotificationsClass);


export { Notifications };
```

(I've removed some useless code)

Top Level :

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
};

@connect(state => ({
    nav: state.nav
}))
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator
                navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                    state: this.props.nav,
                })}
            />
        );
    }
}

const store = getStore(navReducer);

export default function NCAP() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

React : 15.6.1
React-Native : 0.46.4
Redux : 3.7.2
React-Redux : 5.0.5
React-Navigation : 1.0.0-beta.11
Node : 6.9.1

So if you've an idea! It will be great :D !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three issues.

First, React's re-rendering is almost always asynchronous.  In `updateNotifications()`, you are calling `this.props.setNotificationCount(10)`, but attempting to view/use the props later in that function.  Even with the `await` in there, there's no guarantee that `this.props.NotificationCount` will have been updated yet.

Second, based on your reducer structure and `mapState` function, `props.NotificationCount` will actually *never exist*.  In your `getRootReducer()` function, you have:

```
return combineReducers({
    nav: navReducer,
    notificationReducer: NotificationReducer
});
```

That means your root state will be `state.nav` and `state.notificationReducer`.  But, in your `mapState` function, you have:

```
state => ({
    NotificationCount: state.NotificationCount
}),
```

`state.NotificationCount` will never exist, because you didn't use that key name when you called `combineReducers`.

Third, your `notificationReducer` actually has a nested value.  It's returning `{NotificationCount : 0}`.

So, the value you actually want is really at `state.notificationReducer.NotificationCount`.  That means your `mapState` function should actually be:

```
state => ({
    NotificationCount: state.notificationReducer.NotificationCount
}),
```

If your `notificationReducer` isn't actually going to store any other values, I'd suggest simplifying it so that it's just storing the number, not the number inside of an object.  I'd also suggest removing the word `Reducer` from your state slice name.  That way, you could reference `state.notification` instead.

For more info, see the [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) section of the Redux docs, which goes into more detail on how using `combineReducers` defines your state shape.

Comment: Thank you so munch! You're awesome :-) !